# Eclipse Plugin IFile read-only property change

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin

I'm developing a Eclipse Plugin that loads all the project files (IFile) in read-only status.

```
        ResourceAttributes resAttr = new ResourceAttributes();
        resAttr.setReadOnly(true);
        classFile.setResourceAttributes(resAttr);
```

Now when the user starts writing something in the JavaEditor a message box is displayed:

```
File ABC.java is read-only. Do you wish to make it writable?
```

I want to capture the users answer because there are some files that shouldn't be read-only.

In order to do that I have implemented a IElementChangedListener, but I don't know how to get if the IFile read-only propery changed or not.

```
class SinfoniaCloudElementChangedListener implements IElementChangedListener {

@Override
public void elementChanged(ElementChangedEvent event) {
  Activator.logInfo("SinfoniaCloudElementChangedListener - elementChanged");
  try {
    handleDelta(event.getDelta());
  } catch (JavaModelException e) {
    Activator.logError("Error handling delta for ElementChangeListener. ", e);
  }
}

private void handleDelta(IJavaElementDelta delta) throws JavaModelException {
  IJavaElement element = delta.getElement();
  if (element instanceof ICompilationUnit) {
    IJavaProject project = element.getJavaProject();
    if (project.getElementName().equals(SinfoniaProject.getProjectName(true)) == false) {
      return;
    }

    ICompilationUnit cu = (ICompilationUnit) element;
    for (IType type : cu.getAllTypes()) {
      if (type != IType.CLASS_FILE)
        continue;

      switch (delta.getKind()) {
        case IJavaElementDelta.CHANGED:
            Activator.logInfo("CHANGED - Element:" + cu.getElementName());
            // ?????????????????????????????
            break;
           default:
            // do nothing
            break;
        }
    }
  }
  for (IJavaElementDelta child : delta.getAffectedChildren()) {
    handleDelta(child);
  }
 }
}
```

Thank you.

==

As per Andrew suggestion the IElementChangedListener was replaced by IResourceChangeListener, however I'm still don't know how to identify if the IResource read-only property changed or not.

```
class ABCResourceChangeListener implements IResourceChangeListener {

@Override
public void resourceChanged(IResourceChangeEvent event) {
       IResource res = event.getResource();
       try {
         switch (event.getType()) {
            case IResourceChangeEvent.PRE_CLOSE:
               System.out.print("Project ");
               System.out.print(res.getFullPath());
               System.out.println(" is about to close.");
               break;
            case IResourceChangeEvent.PRE_DELETE:
               System.out.print("Project ");
               System.out.print(res.getFullPath());
               System.out.println(" is about to be deleted.");
               break;
            case IResourceChangeEvent.POST_CHANGE:
               System.out.println("Resources have changed.");
        event.getDelta().accept(new DeltaPrinter());
               break;
            case IResourceChangeEvent.PRE_BUILD:
               System.out.println("Build about to run.");
               event.getDelta().accept(new DeltaPrinter());
               break;
            case IResourceChangeEvent.POST_BUILD:
               System.out.println("Build complete.");
               event.getDelta().accept(new DeltaPrinter());
               break;
         }
  } catch (CoreException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
}

class DeltaPrinter implements IResourceDeltaVisitor {
public boolean visit(IResourceDelta delta) {
  IResource res = delta.getResource();
  switch (delta.getKind()) {
    case IResourceDelta.ADDED:
      System.out.print("Resource ");
      System.out.print(res.getFullPath());
      System.out.println(" was added.");
      break;
    case IResourceDelta.REMOVED:
      System.out.print("Resource ");
      System.out.print(res.getFullPath());
      System.out.println(" was removed.");
      break;
    case IResourceDelta.CHANGED:
      System.out.print("Resource ");
      System.out.print(res.getFullPath());
      System.out.println(" has changed.");
      int flags = delta.getFlags();
      if ((flags & IResourceDelta.CONTENT) != 0) {
        System.out.println("--> Content Change");
        // ?????????????????????????
      }
      if ((flags & IResourceDelta.REPLACED) != 0) {
        System.out.println("--> Content Replaced");
      }
      if ((flags & IResourceDelta.MARKERS) != 0) {
        System.out.println("--> Marker Change");
        IMarkerDelta[] markers = delta.getMarkerDeltas();
        // if interested in markers, check these deltas
        for (int j=0; j<markers.length;j++) {
          IMarkerDelta markerDelta = markers[j];
          if (markerDelta.isSubtypeOf(IMarker.SOURCE_ID)) {
            switch (markerDelta.getKind()) {
              case IResourceDelta.ADDED :
                System.out.println("--> Marker Delta Added " );
                break;
              case IResourceDelta.REMOVED :
                System.out.println("--> Marker Delta Removed " );
                break;
              case IResourceDelta.CHANGED:
                System.out.println("--> Marker Delta Changed ");
                break;
            }
          }
        }

      }
      break;
  }
  return true; // visit the children
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`IElementChangedListener` is not what you want.  You should be using an `IResourceChangeListener`.  The listener listens for `IResourceDelta`s.  `IResourceDelta` has a method called `getFlags()` that should return what you want.

See the javadoc for `IWorkspace.addResourceChangeListener(IResourceChangeListener, int)` for more information.

Comment: Hello, so I changed the IElementChangedListener to IResourceChangeListener, and I'm getting the method getFlags. However I 'm still don't know how to find out if the IFile read-only property changed or not.